# Add $_POST value to cart

Tags: php, shopping-cart, cart

I've once downloaded this shopping cart script for my website. 
But now I would like to add a value to the cart but can't figure out how ... :(

I've got the following code :

product.php

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php?action=update">
  <div class="quantity">
    <input type="text" name="qty<?php echo(''.$pinfo->id.''); ?>" value="1" /><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&chi;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="add-quantity">
    <input class="nice-s" type="submit" name="product-quantity-submit" value="ORDER" />
  </div>
</form>
```

cart.php

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cust_cart'];

if(isset($_GET['action'])) {


$action = sanitize($_GET['action']);
switch ($action) {
    case 'add':
        if ($cart) {
            $cart .= ','.$_GET['id'];
        } else {
            $cart = $_GET['id'];
        }
        break;
    case 'delete':
        if ($cart) {
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $newcart = '';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($_GET['id'] != $item) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$item;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            $cart = $newcart;
        }
        break;
    case 'update':
/*  if ($cart) { */
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
                $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
                $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) : explode(',',$cart);
                $newcart = '';
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($id != $item) {
                        if ($newcart != '') {
                            $newcart .= ','.$item;
                        } else {
                            $newcart = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$id;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
/*  }  */
    $cart = $newcart;
    break;
}

}
$_SESSION['cust_cart'] = $cart;
```

What I'd like to know is; how can i add another value to the cart through the product.php page with the following field:

```
  <div class="size">
    <select name="size">
       <option value="16 INCH">16 INCH</option>
       <option value="19 INCH">19 INCH</option>
       <option value="22 INCH">22 INCH</option>
  </div>
```

Thanx in advance!! B)

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<select>` block within the `<form>` tags (**and be sure to close your `<select>` too!** Your example does not display correct syntax.) and you should be able to get the value by accessing the variable `$_POST["size"]`.

I don't know what is being done with this data, but I'd recommend changing the values of each option to something without whitespace.

Comment: Thnx, just made this as an example so forgot to close the select tag (happens to me all the time ;)) What i'd like to achieve is to add this value to the cart. So where the cart now holds i.e. 2 as quantity and $pinfo->id as the product id, i'd like to extend it with the size.

Comment: @JoeyvanBilsen it really depends on which script we're talking here, they're all coded differently and it would be a shot in the dark to say what you should add to make this possible. Some scripts allow you to dynamically configure options like that in the GUI so I'd reccomend reading the documentation for your script and finding a way that way.